# Making a JS formula from slider outputs

Tags: javascript, slider, formula

I'm sure this is possible with JavaScript, but I couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for by searching and my scripting skills are very poor.

I have 3 sliders on a page, which output their value to 3 separate divs (with ids cost, length, income). I would like to have a formula that takes the content of each div and gives a final result, e.g. `result = (income-cost)*length` in a separate div. Ideally, the result would update as each individual slider moved, but maybe a 'calculate' button would be easier?

Here is a [link to the page in question](http://chestervanmen.co.uk/sliders/sliders.htm)

Comment: Could you please show us what you have so far? Or a link to the page in question? Im not really sure what your asking.

Comment: Sorry, should have done that in the first place [link](http://chestervanmen.co.uk/sliders/sliders.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider you have three divs as such as below. Check the code

```
<div id="cost"></div>
<div id="income"></div>
<div id="length"></div>

<div id="total"></div>

<script>
var cost=document.getElementById('cost').innerHTML;
var income=document.getElementById('income').innerHTML;
var length=document.getElementById('length').innerHTML;

var total=(Number(income)-Number(cost))*(Number(length));

//This would give you the total value

document.getElementById('total').innerText=total;//To insert the element into div

</sctipt>
```

Please check the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/ZKTeu/

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get this to work. Here is a [link](http://chestervanmen.co.uk/sliders/sliders.htm) if it helps. And thanks!

Comment: @jtrich I actually did not parse the text into numbers and the divs must have a content before the script is running. So use onload function for determining whether the page is loaded.

Comment: @jtrich I have changed the code and also mentioned a fiddle link. Just go thought the above answer. http://jsfiddle.net/ZKTeu/

Comment: Thanks so much, this works great! As mentioned above I am using sliders to generate the values, so have made a calculate button with onclick. If there is anyway to dynamically change the result as the user moves the slider handle, that would be perfect, but am very happy with this for now. Thanks again!

Comment: @jtrich yes indeed but would you be happy to use JQuery because in case of JavaScript you need to code a lot. I would nit mind showing you the path even if you insist for JavaScript :)

Comment: I am currently using scriptaculous to create the sliders so i would prefer to avoid using conflicting libraries. Could you please give me just the jquery and I will recreate the sliders? Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @jtrich JQuery has a change function. I will point you to the resource.http://api.jquery.com/change/ may be we can take it separately in another question